# Android Button does not startActivity or react to onClick

Tags: android, button, onclick

I'm trying to use a button to start a new activity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2)).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Button clickedBtn = (Button) view;

        switch (clickedBtn.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1: startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivity.class));
                           break;
        case R.id.button2: startActivity(new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class));
                           break;
        }

    }
}
```

But nothing seems to happen when I click on either button. I guess it's because the onClick method does not know which button is actually clicked...but I'm not sure how I can fix this...please advice, thanks!

Edit: added XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000">
 <ScrollView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"> 

<Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="first button" /> 
<Button android:id="@+id/button2" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="second button" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Calling a single listener from multiple views and then checking the source via id as you've done is perfectly acceptable.  It would be prudent to post your main.xml layout as well so we can verify the IDs are correct and you don't have any erroneous tags like `android:onClick` defined on the buttons as well.

Comment: Code looks ok, add logging and check what you have in LogCat.

Comment: What you've done is a quite bad practive - you are supposed to set different onClickListeners for the different views, not just one, and make some strange switch. I would suggest that you refactor it the way `coder` has proposed, although I currently doesn't see a reason what it won't work. Perhaps debugging/logging the ids passed will tell.

Comment: Wow you guys are fast! This is my xml file:

Comment: Wow you guys are fast! I can't post the xml file without going over the character limit, but the xml file looks fine to me...i don't have any method or anything like that defined in my xml file...it's just two buttons inside a LinearLayout. I added this for onClick: Log.d("onClick", "a button gets clicked"); but I don't see anything in my LogCat...I should probably mention that MainActivity is actually a tab, maybe it has something to do with it? @iLate where can I see coder's proposal?

Comment: My XML file (the relevant part) <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:orientation="vertical">"
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="first button"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="second button" />

Comment: Don't listen to what iLate says; Devunwired is right. Spaghetti-fying your code with loads of anonymous *OnClickListener* s, **that's** bad practice.

Comment: Your code works fine on my device without any modifications.  Does the app crash when you press the buttons, or does it actually do nothing?  Did you remember to register `NewActivity` and `AnotherActivity` in the Android Manifest?

Answer (score 0):

I put the code in the wrong file; everything is working now. Thanks!